# How can I protect the routes in a react application using Firebase as the backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to protect the routes and do the roles authorisation, and authentication in a react website. But I couldn’t find a fast way of doing it. I.e. Different buttons on the AppBar are hidden or shown based on the role of the user. But I couldn’t find anything that could help me achieve that apart from querying the database.

I’m protecting the routes currently using the roles authorisation, and authentication, which queries firebase database and firebase auth for the roles and the assigned user respectively.

Comment: You would fetch your User from Firebase once when you load up your app and store the role in a global state management system like Redux or Flux. Then you would read that role value in your Router and show your links based on the global role.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom there is a component prop and the value pass to component prop is component wrapped with hoc. Below is the way to use it:-

```
<Route exact path="/yourpathhere" component={checkAllotedRoutes(yourComponent)} />
//In the above route component is basically a hook check.
export default function checkAllotedRoutes(Component) {
  class Permissions extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      location: PropTypes.object,
    };

    permissionAvailable = (locationKey) => {
     // see if location is there in permission array 
     return permissions.includes(locationKey);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.permissionAvailable(this.props.location.key);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      // not 100% sure about using `locatoin.key` to distinguish between routes
      if (nextProps.location.key !== this.props.location.key) {
        this.permissionAvailable(nextProps.location.key);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return React.createElement(Component, { ...this.props });
    }
  }

  Permissions.propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object,
  };

  return Permissions;
}
```

In the above code the component is pass inside the hoc where we will check the permission.